# Desktop showed in weird colors after coming out of a suspend in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, gpu-driver

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 hoping to fix an xHCI issue, but instead I got another problem. I have the following video controller:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks PRO [Radeon HD 7570] [1002:675d]
```

There are no errors in `dmesg` related to radeon.  After a few (like 2-3) suspends, the desktop is displayed in weird colors. I have to log out and back in again, but that's a pain.

Anybody else experiencing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

dmesg doesn't hold all the answers. Many times I'll look at /var/log/syslog to find errors not listed by dmesg.

Like yourself I also recently upgraded to 16.04 due to solicitation during daily 14.04 updates. I too had "glitches" and the first thing I had to do on my platform was update Kernel from 4.4 to 4.6.3. Still some little things to work out but 16.04 has brought many improvements. Good Luck.